# Server Error 404 - File or directory not found

Tags: javascript, server, custom-error-pages

When I browse my site for the first time it will show me this (see attachment below)
[Server Error 404 - File or directory not found. The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iTzDz.png)

But when I browse it again, the site seems fine. This is my site's URL https://firstchoicelimonj.com/  Is there anyone who encounters this kind of error? it would help me a lot if someone can help me with this. Thank you so much!

Comment: so, it happened just once, but now works, right? I get that error every time on your site

Comment: No, it is still happening. Still facing the issue.

Comment: but you said the error happened only the the first time. So, it's EVERY time - perhaps you've misconfigured Microsoft IIS - it's pretty tricky to set up correctly if you want to use PHP

Comment: I'm not that good at English so I can't really explain the problem, but you cant try clicking my website URL . it will show you the error then try browsing it again then it will be fine.

Comment: nope, it's NEVER fine, it's ALWAYS error (sorry, was using the IP address you posted in the image)

Comment: Webiste blocked by internet use policy.  See [this meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Comment: yeah that's what I'm telling when you click the URL it will show an error but try pasting the site url again in a new tab then it will be fine.

Comment: the domain points to 35.226.43.47 - so ... why did you originally post an IP address 176.113.115.10 - perhaps that's the issue ... some weird sh*t going on with DNS resolution

Comment: what do you mean? It is a WordPress website and it is connected to WPengine, then I connected it to IONOS hosting, but honestly, I don't really know how DNS works can you help me?

Comment: @JaromandaX FYI I get 176.113.115.10, but it's blocked

Comment: Does anyone knows how to fix this issue?

Comment: In my case (as you said), first click 404, then I copied the text and paste it on Chrome, works fine. Now when I click the link it works. I think after first click, it directs the file set.php, If I were you I check what's inside set.php or you manually redirect your website to index.php (htaccess)

Comment: Yeah, that's what the issue I have. but the thing is that I don't have enough knowledge about PHP. And I can find what you're talking to